# Program Skipped An Input

Tags: c

I'm on intro to C programming course and I'm a bit confused here. There are 4 input and the first 3 work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nRyq.png) completely fine but when it comes to the fourth the program just skipped that input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    float a, b, c, period, e, f, g, h, loan, interest, repayment, fee; 
    printf("** Calculator for Furniture Loan **");
    printf("\n______________________________________\n");
    printf("Enter purchase price: RM "); scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter down payment: RM "); scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Enter interest rate (%%): "); scanf("%0.2f", &c) ;
    printf("Enter repayment period (year): "); scanf("%f, &period");
    printf("\n*****************************************");
    printf("\nPurchase Price: RM %.0f", a);
    printf("\nDown Payment: RM %.0f", b);
    printf("\nInterest Rate: %0.2f percent", c);
    printf("\nRepayment Period: %lf year(s)", period);
    printf("\n*****************************************\n");
    loan = a - b;
    printf("Loan Amount: RM %.0f", loan);
    interest = loan * c / 100;
    printf("\nTotal Interest: RM %.2f", interest);
    repayment = loan + interest;
    printf("\nTotal Loan Repayment: RM %.2f", repayment);
    fee = repayment / (period * 12);
    printf("\nMonthly Repayment: RM %.2f", fee);
    printf("\n*****************************************\n");
    printf("Table of Repayment");
    printf("\nMonth"); printf("\t\t Payment (RM)"); printf("\tAccumulated Payment (RM)"); printf("\tBalance (RM)");
    printf("\n1"); printf("\t\t %.2f", fee); printf("\t\t%.2f", fee); printf("\t\t\t\t%.2f", repayment-fee);
    printf("\n2"); printf("\t\t %.2f", fee); printf("\t\t%.2f", fee*2); printf("\t\t\t\t%.2f", repayment-fee*2);
    printf("\n3"); printf("\t\t %.2f", fee); printf("\t\t%.2f", fee*3); printf("\t\t\t\t%.2f", repayment-fee*3);
    printf("\n4"); printf("\t\t %.2f", fee); printf("\t\t%.2f", fee*4); printf("\t\t\t\t%.2f", repayment-fee*4);
    printf("\n5"); printf("\t\t %.2f", fee); printf("\t\t%.2f", fee*5); printf("\t\t\t\t%.2f", repayment-fee*5);
}
```

Comment: I've changed the printf("\nRepayment Period: %lf year(s)", period); to printf("\nRepayment Period: %f year(s)", period) but the program is still skipping the fourth input.

Comment: `scanf("%f, &period");`  --> `scanf("%f", &period);`

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`. See [this link](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for further information.

Comment: Tried changing it to scanf("%f", &period); but the program is still skipping the 4th input

Comment: @user3121023 thank you so much. The program works perfectly fine now.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) single letter variable names, like `a`, `b`, `c`, are meaningless, even in the current context. Suggest names like: `purchasePrice` `downPayment` and `interestRate`

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 3):

Check the below line. You should end the quote before comma(),

just replace

```
scanf("%f, &period");
```

with

```
scanf("%f", &period);
```

I have not tested it but it would work fine.

Comment: ... and check the return value as well

Comment: I've changed it to scanf("%f", &period); but the program is still skipping the 4th input

Comment: @jcjh99, what do you want to achieve with 0.2f in the line "scanf("%0.2f", &c);"? Actually, this statement is creating a problem for you.

Comment: @CodingbyRaj I just wanted the input to be 2 decimal places.

Comment: It doesn't matter on input, the internal representation will be the same.  They only time you need to care about decimal places is when writing output

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @user3121023, my program works after changing scanf("%0.2f", &c) to scanf("%f", &c). Also thank you to CodingbyRaj and dragosht for pointing my careless mistakes.